# jQuery on change refer to this.value and this

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, this

Let's say I have a bit of code like this that runs on change of a select:

```
$('select[name="nights"]').on('change', function() {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

Is there any way I can have a reference to my global this object(if it's called that) without using something like:

```
var self = this;
```

Using something like a bind destroys the reference to the jQuery select element:

```
$('select[name="nights"]').on('change', function() {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

I wan't to be more concise and understanding of scope though so I prefer binding rather than saving reference to this. If I look at code standards from airbnb for example they rather not use `self = this` reference as well.

https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#naming--self-this

I am wondering how they get around this like stuff though where you both need a local scope reference to this and a this reference to your global object.

Am I simply forced to still make a reference or is there any way around this? I might simply be overthinking and nitpicking here but I am hoping for an elegant solution, else I might as well stick with saving references in the first place.

Comment: Are you talking about the global object, which is **Window** in the browser platform ?

Comment: Just my global this reference which I use to refer the my methods and properties that I have set. So yeah I'm guessing the window?

Comment: With jquery, $(this) , not this

Comment: Not what I am looking for, that just turns it into something I can manipulate with jQuery but that does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTICE**: 
In your case i think you want to access the value of the select element, if so you 
can use :

```
$(this).val();
```

instead of

```
this.value;
```

If you want to access the global `this` value, which is **Window** in the browser platform, you have two options:

**Option 1:**

If you want the ES5 way you can use an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) function, for example :

```
var that = (function(){return this;}());
```

**option 2:**

If you want the ES6 way, which is better with less code to write, for example:

```
const that = (()=>this)(); // .... (*)
```

Where (*) is the equivalent of the previous ES5 code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure weather I understand your question.

With #bind (ES5 way)

```
$('select[name="nights"]').on('change', function(){
  console.log(this.value);
}.bind(this));
```

> From https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
>
> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

ES6 way

> From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions
>
> Lexical this
>
> Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own this value (a new object in case of a constructor, undefined in strict mode function calls, the context object if the function is called as an "object method", etc.). This proved to be annoying with an object-oriented style of programming.
>
> An arrow function does not create its own this context; rather, it captures the this value of the enclosing context, so the following code works as expected.(I didn't copy the code)

so, you can to it with arrow function

```
$('select[name="nights"]').on('change', () => {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```